# Is there any dictionary in linux shell like in Python dictionary method

Tags: python, linux, shell, dictionary

inputfile.txt:

```
load1: apples,oranges
load2: vegetables,fruits
```

Pythoncode:

```
d = {}
with open('inputfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ":" not in line:
            continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value
```

In above python code, I will read input file and send values to key and value.

Then i will make use of this in program.

As I need to write script in shell, Is there any similar method in Linux shell scripting. Please help to achieve this in linux shell.

or any other method is also fine as long as i can able achieve above

I am using sh shell in linux

Comment: There are lots of shells you can use with Linux. Which one are *you* using?

Comment: @chepner sh shell

Comment: That's actually not a shell; `/bin/sh` is a link or copy of a shell that supports the POSIX shell specification, such as `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc.